# Google map showing gray box instead of google map using javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Here I am trying to display my map using `javascript` but its showing a gray box instead of map, and its not showing any error in console.

Here is image of my map:

[image]

Please help to solve it. Thanks in advance.

Here is my code:

```js
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init);

function init() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 11,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.767089, -73.969458),
    scrollwheel: false,
    disableDefaultUI: true,
    styles: [{
      stylers: [{
        hue: '#2c3e50'
      }, {
        saturation: 250
      }]
    }, {
      featureType: 'road',
      elementType: 'geometry',
      stylers: [{
        lightness: 50
      }, {
        visibility: 'simplified'
      }]
    }, {
      featureType: 'road',
      elementType: 'labels',
      stylers: [{
        visibility: 'off'
      }]
    }]
  };

  var mapElement = document.getElementById('map_canvas');

  var map = new google.maps.Map(mapElement, mapOptions);

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: map.getCenter(),
    map: map,
    title: 'Click to zoom'
  });
}
```

```css
html {
  height: 100%
}
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}
#map_canvas {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
#map_canvas * {
  overflow: visible;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MyKeyhere"></script>
<div id="map_canvas" style="width: 600px; height: 600px; position: relative;">
</div>
```

Comment: I have tested your code and it is working. What type of key did you use? Check this [document](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key), if you will be using Google Maps JavaScript API you must use a **browser key** (a type of API key)

Comment: When you look at network activity in browser console what is status code of requests for tiles? Requests are like https://www.google.com/maps/vt?....

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this helps:

I am using a diffrent mapOptions on my website with mapTypeIds set.

```
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 19,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng( 51.7734896,4.6764931),
        mapTypeControlOptions: {
            mapTypeIds: [google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, 'map_style']
        }
    };
```

Comment: but its cant help to make may map styles

Comment: perhaps looking at the code behind on my site helps? I'm using a custom theme style on the google.maps myself: http://www.edwardpieper.nl/?c=contact